# Can you help identify this sound effect?

Tags: sound-effects, noise, sound-fx

Can any of you help me identify this sound effect?

https://instaud.io/1GDq

You help is strongly appreciated.

Cheers!

Comment: Identify in what way? It's all a bit vague & shows no research.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like dust and scratches from a playing vinyl record.
There are many plugins that can help you with that, for instance [iZotope Vinyl](https://www.izotope.com/en/products/create-and-design/vinyl.html) which is free.

There is something else to it though: a filter-like movement, which could be a phaser effect or simply an EQ filter.

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to say for sure, but my guess is a contact microphone on some form of, maybe plastic, getting cut up or sheared. Or having something dragged on it. If so, I take it this comes from something already mixed, as the voice is impossible to get that way.

Even more likely though - It might also just be a cellphone or small recorder being dragged on a concrete or asphalt surface. Sounds too full to be just a simple microphone. Where did you find it?

Answer (score 0):

Sounds to me like someone cutting glass with a diamond-tipped hand tool.